# How to solve "for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list" error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

There is a `Company` model that has columns `total_standard_score` and `code`.
And the company has many `share_holders`. The model has `pagination`.

#### company.rb

```
scope :share_holder, -> name {
  joins(:share_holders).where("share_holders.name LIKE '%#{name}%'") if name.present?
}
```

#### companies_controller.rb

```
sort_string = "total_standard_score is null, total_standard_score desc, code asc"
Company.select('companies.*').share_holder('name').order(sort_string).distinct
```

This code fails with error: `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

What should I add to select statement for `total_standard_score is null, total_standard_score desc, code asc`?

This is result of `to_sql`.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT companies.* FROM \"companies\" INNER JOIN \"share_holders\" ON \"share_holders\".\"company_id\" = \"companies\".\"id\" WHERE (share_holders.name LIKE '%name%')  ORDER BY total_standard_score is null, total_standard_score desc, code asc"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, this is your query (in a more readable form)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM companies c INNER JOIN
     share_holders sh
     ON sh.company_id = c.id
WHERE sh.name LIKE '%name%' 
ORDER BY c.total_standard_score is null, c.total_standard_score desc, c.code asc;
```

I suspect the problem is the expression on `c.total_standard_score`.  That *shouldn't* be a problem, but it might be.

Your underlying database might support `NULLS LAST`:

```
ORDER BY c.total_standard_score desc nulls last, c.code asc;
```

But a more efficient way to write the query is to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM companies c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM share_holders sh
              WHERE sh.company_id = c.id AND sh.name LIKE '%name%'
             ) 
ORDER BY c.total_standard_score is null, c.total_standard_score desc, c.code asc;
```

This should not have any parsing problems and be more efficient as well.

Comment: Thanks. To use same function in Rails I need to install `                     `where_exists` gem. And it works with `Company.where(:share_holders, ['name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%"]).order(sort_string)`.